# Cherry MX Blue mechanical keyboard with RGB backlighting

Tags: keyboards

I'm looking for a [Cherry MX Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_(keyboards)#Cherry_switches_in_consumer_keyboards_.28circa_mid_2016.29) keyboard with RGB backlighting. I'm using a [Razer BlackWidow 2013](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-keyboards-keypads/razer-blackwidow-2013) first revision, and I love the switches on it. I have tried [MX Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_(keyboards)#Cherry_switches_in_consumer_keyboards_.28circa_mid_2016.29) switches, but I'm not happy with the click.

It's not for the near future, so if you know keyboards that are going to launch with it be sure to add it. I have an UNLIMITED budget for this keyboard.

It's going to be used for games, but mostly for the typing of stuff. I'm a heavy typer so I would like to get one where the legs don't pop off.

Comment: I would advise you first find out if blue is indeed the switch you want. Red is supposed to be for gaming, but I found (on a new Corsair K95) it to be horrible for moba games where constantly pressed buttons are rare and it's all about the timing of a single press (also - completely unlike my laptop). Since returning these is a pain after you've unpacked and tried it, and they are also reasonably expensive, you'd probably want on of [these](http://www.amazon.com/Max-Keyboard-Keycap-Cherry-Sampler/dp/B00E71W4O8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409795458&sr=8-1&keywords=mechanical+switch+tester) babies.

Comment: Good idea. So far i had Blue, Razer greens, browns clears rubberdom butterfly and chicklet. also tryed the new macbook switches but they are not for a external keyboard. I realy like the click of the blues, Maybe toper typeheaven are good ones for me but I heard they are also non RGB.

Comment: If your budget is truly unlimited, why not just have one custom-made? probably only going to be a few thousand dollars.

Comment: I don't think Cherry MX Blue RGB are made anymore. if they can garantee me 10 year stabel click then i would considder getting one. I need one about every 2 year becaus of switch deprevation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Another official Cherry MX Blue RGB option has become available recently, the Cooler Master [MasterKeys Pro L/S](http://amzn.to/2m0YfBE). This keyboard is not exactly new, but I ignored it for some time after the Cherry MX Blue versions were originally delayed. The keyboard is currently out and available for anyone looking at options besides the Corsair keyboard.

<s>**EDIT:** Since I first wrote this answer, ***Corsair has surprisingly brought back the [K70 RGB](http://amzn.to/1S5VxmH) in Cherry MX Blue switches.*** They were available on Amazon a few days ago, but quickly sold out.</s> Unfortunately, it seems these aren't going to be restocked, meaning the Strafe RGB is likely the best option for Cherry MX Blue.

The [Corsair Strafe RGB](http://amzn.com/B014W1YLAM) is available in Cherry MX Blue switches, and is a great option if you cannot wait for the K70 RGB Blue. The reviews for this keyboard have improved over the last few months, and the one I tried had no problems.

<s>One of the previous answers mentioned the G.Skill KM780 keyboard, and the [KM780R RGB](http://amzn.com/B0186W6PGQ) is now available for preorder, unless Amazon is lying to us.</s> The RGB version of this keyboard probably will never be available for Cherry MX Blue switches. The Amazon pages for the KM780R MX Blue RGB no longer exist.

There is also the [Poseidon Z RGB](http://amzn.to/1WNWaJw) keyboard, which is relatively cheap for an RGB keyboard. This keyboard does **NOT** have genuine Cherry MX switches (Kalih Blue), and I would only buy this as a last option, because some complain about the switches breaking after awhile of use.

Answer (score 4):

MX Blue switches are known to have the most tactile feedback and loudest click of Cherry's MX range. If you are using it for gaming (which from the Razer I am guessing you are), you want to be looking at the MX Cherry Red Keyboards. These have light feedback and a quieter click, allowing for a much smoother game. There is a good answer explaining on [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2788814/cherry-blue-brown-switches-keyboard.html).

You cannot find many Cherry MX Blue RGB keyboards as RGB keyboards; these are generally designed for gamers, and gamers tend to use MX Red. There were the Corsair K70 and K95 RGB MX Cherry blue keyboards, however, these are available on the Corsair website but seem to have been discontinued in many stores.

I would suggest the equivalent [Corsair K70 RGB Mechanical Keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014W1Z4LC). It has Cherry MX Red switches for smooth gaming and fully programmable RGB backlighting; it also has a lot of effects on the lighting, and solid software to do this. It is also the latest 2016 edition just released, so no worries of a newer version arriving soon.

Comment: :/, i was affraid for that. the problem is i don't like the liniar bump. i've heard is the same/close feeling to rubber dome which i'm not a fan of at all. I just don't understand why the MX Blue line is so unpopulair. also if i need a shalow depth of field click i tend to use a chicklet or butterfly keyboard so response time is no issue here.

Comment: Since you enjoy the Razer why don't you try the new Razer BlackWidow Chroma? Razerhave their own brand of mechanical switches but i am not sure about the noise level of the key presses.

Comment: I've tryed one of there new razer switches and they have a very metal clink. like i said i was luckey and got a Cherry MX version.

Answer (score 3):

Josh Spoors does a great explanation on the different switches, so I'm not going to do it again. But what I am going to do is to recommend you a product. Since the K70 RGB with Blue Switch is discontinued, there is another great product. Let me introduce you to the [GSkill KM780 RGB](http://www.gskill.com/en/press/view/g-skill-announces-availability-of-new-cherry-rgb-mx-mechanical-gaming-keyboards) with the Cherry MX Blue switch. GSkill is new to the keyboard market but is a very good player in the RAM industry. Their first attempt at a keyboard is great. It is solidly built, comes with genuine Cherry MX Switches, and has almost all the features a K70 has.

Comment: Cool thanks for the suggestion. but they don't make or haven't made the blues yet, on there site i cain't find the blue edition of the keyboard.

Comment: @Thomcdrom Where are you located?

Comment: The Netherlands, but I can import for the USA

Comment: It says on the page cherry blues will be available at a later date :) so as you are not requiring it right this second, you may be able to wait it out...it is a very good looking keyboard though!